# Can an instruction with a dependency read the register in same cycle as it's being written?

Tags: cpu-pipelines

I'm learning about superscalar processors and struggling with it a bit. I wrote an assembly program and now must move it through in-order in-issue completion and I have a question about instructions as they move through the latter stages of the pipeline.

I have two instructions I1 and I2. I1 performs an operation on R1 and R2 and then loads the result in to R1. I2 needs read the new result of R1 and then overwrite R1, but obviously cannot do so until R1 is finished, otherwise I1 will be incorrect. At what point will I2 be able to correctly read the new result of R1? While I1 is in the WB stage or once I1 has finished the WB stage?

Thanks! I also realize this may not be an ideal design, but it's what I have to work with. Also, if this is not CS related and belongs in a different stack exchange, please move.

Answer (score 2):

With modern processors, arithmetic units tend to be able to deliver results simultaneously to a register, and to another arithmetic unit that requires that result.

There is a limit to this, so if you have three add instructions "x = a + b, y = x + x, z = x + x", then the a+b operation is unlikely to be able to send the result to a register, and to four inputs of two more additions. Even reading from a register is likely limited, so in this extreme example you could have (assuming an adder can forward to one input and a register, and registers can be read by two inputs):

```
Cycle 0: Adds a+b, sends result to x and first input of y = x + x.
Cycle 1: y = x + x reads second input from x; z = x + x reads first input from x
Cycle 2: Adds x + x, sends result to y. z = x + x reads second input
Cycle 3: Adds x + x, sends result to z.
```

On the other hand, take x = a + b, y = x + a, z = x + b:

```
Cycle 0: Adds a + b, sends result to x and first input of y = x + a
         y = x + a reads a, z = x + b reads b.
Cycle 1: Adds x + a, sends result to y. z = x + b reads x.
Cycle 2: Adds x + b, sends to z.
```

So an instruction cannot read a register at the time it is written to, but often results can be forwarded to an instruction at the same time they are written to a register.